# Return Content Only In Socket C++

Tags: c++, sockets

Is there a way to have a socket response only return the content of the page and not the header?

Example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 16 Mar 2016 02:38:20 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dad831f7d4a53291c3c112ebe9410205a1458095900; expires=Thu, 16-Mar-17 02:38:20 GMT; path=/; domain=.(my personal site);
HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.32
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 2844d412d5621159-DFW

<body>
  <p>
    Hello World!
  </p>
</body>
```

and I want it to look like

```
<body>
  <p>
    Hello World!
  </p>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What you read from the socket is what you read. There are no pushbutton setting that says "I want to read from the socket, but please ignore everything up until the first blank line". It's up to you to write the code that reads from the socket, and parses the wanted input.

Comment: Throwing away everything up to the empty line isn't that hard.  Just look for two line ends in a row.   That's http's end of headers mark

Comment: If you're going to implement HTTP you need a good knowledge of RFC 2616, but there really isn't any need given that so many HTTP libraries already exist.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for the quick response. I was originally going to put on there that I am developing for PS3 and there is very little support for char arrays but I felt like it was unnecessary. Nevertheless, do you know what characters are between the cf-ray line and <body> tag? I tried strstr(response,"\n\n"); but it gave me some weird character that was like ascii 6000.

Comment: @infixed please read my above comment.

Comment: all line ends are not created equal.  For example \r\n\r\n would be equally valid.  If you have a more exact sequence than 'like ascii 6000', may there would be an insight

Comment: @gopro_2027 Between DFW and <body> should be \r\n\r\n.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating my own stuff for it

```
int getIndexOf(char *string, char *find, int startindex = 0, bool addonlength = false) {
    for (int i = startindex; i < strlen(string); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(find); j++) {
            if (string[i+j] == find[j]) {
                if (j == strlen(find)-1) {
                    if (addonlength)
                        i+=strlen(find);
                    return i;
                }
            } else {
                j = strlen(find);
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
void substring(char string[], int x, int y) {
    int len = strlen(string);
    //underneath x
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if (i < len)
            string[i] = 0;
    }
    //above y
    for (int i = y; i < strlen(string); i++) {
        if (i < len)
            string[i] = 0;
    }
    //moving the rest down
    for (int i = x; i < y; i++) {
        if (i < len)
            string[i-x] = string[i];
    }
}
```

and to actually use it

```
char networkSearchString[] = "\r\n\r\n";
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    ConsoleWrite("\n");
ConsoleWrite("Printing...\n");
char *text = SocketRequest("google.com","search?q=hey");
int in = getIndexOf(text,networkSearchString,0,true);
substring(text,in,strlen(text));
ConsoleWrite(text);
ConsoleWrite("\nDone");
```

Comment: Nah, this mostly reinvents a bunch of wheels. It can probably rewritten into three or four lines of code.

Comment: @VeronikaPrüssels, no, it is not. It is very low quality code. strlen called in a loop multiple times, using c-style strings in C++, don't even get me started.

Comment: @SergeyA I understand the code isn't the best. I probably should have optimized it a little bit before posting.